# create dataframes from selected csv files in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, indexing

I have a series of csv files like this:

```
dataframe_1 <- read.csv('C:filepath/data_1.csv', header = T, skip = 1)
```

Where each file is a year of records. The number varies from run to run, so one time might be only a few, other times dozens of files. What I've been doing is creating individual dataframes, stripping out the columns I want using:

```
cutout_1 <- dataframe_1[c(1:365), c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)]
```

and then binding them with rbind() as follows:

```
total <- rbind(cutout_1, cutout_2, cutout_3, cutout_4)
as.data.frame(total)
```

However this is clunky and I need to re-write every time I change something about the model I am using, such as the number of years (and thus the number of files it produces), which wastes a lot of time.

I have tried indexing through the data file, but can't seem to find a way to extract only the files I want, nor find a way to skip the first row, which is essential because of the way the data is produced which I have no control over.

Comment: Do the filenames follow a pattern or are they all in the same directory? This is many times solved before the files are read in to a list, then a sequence of instructions processes them all in one `lapply` loop. Also, a simplification of the posted code is to realize that since `cutout_*` are data.frames, you are calling the `rbind` method for class `"data.frame"` and the final `as.data.frame` is redundant.

Comment: All files are in the same directory/filepath, and share the same name (example: Day_Climate_*) * being number of a year so they need to be in that order. There are other files with different names in the folder, which are also structured slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the working directory is the directory where the files can be found, the code below first gets the filenames, then reads them in a `lapply` loop and creates a `cutout` column with the file base name without directory path nor extension. Then `rbind`s them in one data.frame.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "Day_Climate_.*\\.csv")

cols_to_keep <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
rows_to_keep <- 1:365

cutout_list <- lapply(filenames, \(x) {
  dftmp <- read.csv(x, skip = 1L)
  dftmp <- dftmp[rows_to_keep, cols_to_keep]
  # these instructions create in each file 
  # a column telling where they came from
  # (this might not be needed)
  cutout <- basename(x)
  cutout <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(cutout)
  dftmp$cutout <- cutout
  # need to return the anonymous function value
  dftmp
})

total <- do.call(rbind, cutout_list)
```

Comment: One thing though, whereas in this I get a list of 20 (there are 20 files), when I transfer to another filename, changing nothing else, the cutout only extracts 9 of the files. I don't see why this would be happening.

Comment: @Bob Is `pattern` getting all of the filenames? Check its content before the loop, if its length is 9 then you'll get 9 files only.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. Pattern is only returning 9 files. I can however look in the file (in RStudio and directly) and see that there are 20 files in this list. I did edit the 'skip' to 4L, and had to add 'header = F' to get it to read the files into file_keep <- read.csv.

Comment: apparently it was a missing '.' before *\\ in the pattern. "FileName_.*\\.csv"

Comment: @Bob Without the period the pattern is looking the string without the underscore `"Day_Climate"` followed by  `"_"` repeated zero or more times (`"*"`), with the pattern it becomes the string with the underscore `"Day_Climate_"` followed by any char `"."` repeated zero or more times.

Comment: @Bob As for `header=F`, you can also use `file_keep<-read.table(., sep = ",", skip=4L)`. `read.csv is a wrapper around `read.table` with some defaults set, including header and sep.